# Is it possible to use ADFS 4.0 as STS for Winforms->WCF?

Tags: wcf, wif, adfs, windows-server-2016, adfs4.0

Our Winforms application talks to a WCF service, and I need to implement claims-based authorization. Both use NET Framework 4.5.2

Per this [link](http://bartwullems.blogspot.ru/2013/11/visual-studio-2013-where-is-identity.html), no STS tooling is available for VS 2015, I'm up to installing VS 2012 on a separate workstation for this development. I just want to use the tool in VS 2012 to help me figure out the configuration needed.

Most documentation for ADFS 4.0 is for Azure and WebAPI, I can't find single example of setting up with Windows Server 2016-ADFS 4.0+WCF.

Is it possible to use WIF to configure WCF service for ADFS 4.0/Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 4.0 still supports WS-Federation and the WS-* endpoints are all still there.

So yes.

There's a sample [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748481.aspx).

Just be careful because you need WIF 4.5 not WIF 3.5 for Server 2016.